Is there a comprehensive list of arguments for Christian theism?
On the internet, one can find articles like 100 Reasons to Believe that God Does Not Exist written by atheists. Are there any articles/papers/books that, on contrary, compile a large number of arguments for why God exists? Something like "400 reasons to believe that God exists" or "78 arguments for Christianity"

This list will be constantly updated.

Over 200 Academic Arguments for the Existence of God

1000 Reasons to Believe

1000 Responses To 1000 Objections and Arguments Against Christianity

Reasons We Believe: 50 Lines of Evidence That Confirm the Christian Faith

Evidence for God: 50 Arguments for Faith from the Bible, History, Philosophy, and Science

100 Reasons to Believe

30 Abbreviated Arguments for the Existence of God



Chesterton summed up why he was Catholic by, instead of listing 10,000 reasons simply said "Because it is true"
But prior to becoming Catholic he was asked to make a defense of Christianity and wrote a book called Orthodoxy which is the only thing anyone ever really needs to read on the subject, besides the Bible.
Here are all the reasons in Orthodoxy:

It has the feeling of coming home
It preserves the romance, poetry and imagination
It is the end of one's search for truth
It is the heresy that men of goodwill would found
It is both good doctrine and good ethics
It helps people be sane
It clearly points out positive evil
It upholds the common man as a hero
It is expansive
It answers questions in their entirety.
It is against materialism, but reverences the human body
It is against spiritualism, but for mysticism
It is against presumption and despair
It has symbols, but rejects idolatry
It is against suicide, but loves martyrs
It is for humility, but builds towers to worship God
It encourages men to question, but not to be convinced in their scepticism
It allows for evolution, but acknowledges God's hand in the process
It points its adherents toward moral truths, no matter what the fads or fashions are
It encourages a balance of faith and reason
It does not admire the "will to power" of man, but seeks the Will of God
It upholds as its best and brightest those who "Do things", whether in a corporal or spiritual way.
It can work with any political scheme (except ones that persecute it specifically), but especially is compatible with democracy and the brotherhood of man.
It upholds tradition as the "Democracy of the Dead". Teaches that we should respect our ancestors, but not worship them.
It does not deny the truths we learned in infancy, from fairy stories, but extends them into reality.
It does not posit a God who can deny Himself.
It shows that God loves and enjoys us as His special part of creation.
It teaches monogamy
It is the right shape for mankind
It is a living thing
It teaches that God is creative and energetic
It creates a fondness for itself in mankind
It provides us with all the tools we need for salvation
It encourages temperance
It encourages patriotism
It abhors anarchy
It encourages us to make the world a better place
It encourages us to bind each other in matrimony
It encourages us to keep our word
It was the first to preach Christianity
It came to destroy the doctrine of the Inner Light (sorry Quakers / stoics)
It recognized a need in man to worship something besides self
It does not worship health, but enjoys it when it is good.
It does not worship sex, but encourages procreation
It acknowledges a clear separation between Creator and creation
It allows a man to feel homesick at home
It shares the same quirks as mankind
It is attacked for contradictory reasons:

too gloomy / too merry
too timid / too brash
too poor / too rich
just an ethical code / just a bunch of dogma
pardons too much / too judgmental


it is not a safe religion - does not have a safe God.
the rules are like the walls of a playground
contains all manner of frightful pleasures
does not treat man as equal with nature, but above it
Has Christmas
Encourages reform over revolution or progress for progress's sake
It allows us to denounce slavery, even if we might be hypocrites
It preserves a permanent ideal that we should strive toward
It acknowledges that the attainment of that ideal will not be on Earth.
It turns conservatism into action instead allowing things to corrupt.
It acknowledges the Fall of Mankind (original sin)
It is the only thing left that can question the powerful and elite.
It does not believe in eugenics
It does not believe in life in prison
It has a preferential option for the poor
It teaches that accumulation of wealth is a danger for the soul of man.
It does not trust people simply because they are rich
It believes that the "weaknesses make one strong"
It does not believe seriousness is a virtue
It gives us real obligations to go with our adventures
It has miracles and acknowledges God's power to work among us freely.
It is not Buddhism.
It bears resemblances to other religions, but entirely different creeds.
It teaches that God is a society (in the Trinity)
It teaches that anyone could be damned, but it is wicked to refer to someone as damned.
It teaches that death (and birth) is an exciting moment.
It helps people to be cured of their sins.
It shows that God needed to walk among us to be complete.
It has a virtuous God man as its King.
It is the only religion in which God "seemed for an instant to be an athiest"
Its enemies use any weapon against it.
All possible evidence points to it being true.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority

@Valorum I hope your happy, because I was very happy to take the last hour to compile that list.

Am I happy that you've improved your answer? Yes. And you should be too.

@Valorum is citing church fathers also argument from authority? cause oh boy the orthodox church does that a lot.

"It is not Buddhism" seems entirely irrelevant

@Valorum you might want to read the book then, Chesterton devotes a chapter to why Christianity is not Buddhism, especially Buddhism.

@PeterTurner - I'm aware of the symbolism, but Chesterton seems entirely reliant on a fictionalised Western-centric version of Christianity as a demonstrably powerful reforming force for good (which it hasn't always been), and Buddhism as a sullen insular force for the status quo. I'm pretty sure a Buddhist would point at the cathedrals that Chesterton so lauds as indicative of Christian advancement, as a colossal waste of money that could have been spent feeding and clothing the poor.

@Valorum I don't think he sugar coats the problems of Christianity entirely, it's easy to say he does, but he goes pretty strong into why we should have a sentiments like patriotism toward our faith.   he wrote that saying "My country right or wrong" is not a patriotic sentiment, it is like saying "my mother drunk or sober"

As for buddhism, I'm sure he is not talking about actual buddhists, but those who wrongly believe that buddhism is compatible with Christianity or that if you distilled them both they would be the same thing.  He's defending buddhists insofar as they are buddhists.  But attacking the weak and pointless notion that "everything is everything".

There are several that come up from a quick search:

50 reasons to believe in God
10 Reasons to Believe in The Existence of God
10 Reasons to Believe in the Christian Faith
31 Reasons to Believe in the God of the Bible
6 Reasons Point to God's Existence
10 Proofs for Existence of God
10 Good Reasons to Believe in God and Christianity
10 Reasons to Believe in God


I've got a few bookmarked actually. They are aligned with my Eastern Orthodox Perspectives of course, and they aren't really a list format, they are written in the form of an article.
Metropolitan of Gortyn and Megalopolis, Ieremias "Proof that God exists"
Pravmir.com has some articles.
https://www.pravmir.com/arguing-god-s-existence/
https://www.pravmir.com/god-s-existence/
And there is this article by Fr Freeman

A Book with an Infallible ListingWithout intending to be frivolous nor facetious, there is another Book with a comprehensive list that must not be overlooked: it begins with Genesis, Exodus...and ends with Jude, Revelation!
Proof that God Exists is manifest from a listing of the straight-forward teaching, and factual recording of history, in the Bible:

The Self-Revelation of God, by God Himself: God talking to mankind all throughout history (Exodus 3, Hebrews 1:1-2)

The scientific evidence recorded in Genesis, that Time, Matter, Energy had a "beginning" long before Science discovered this (Genesis 1:1, Isaiah 45:12, 18)

The miraculous presentation of Health Laws in the Torah before modern science ever caught on (Deuteronomy 14:1-21)

The supernatural prophetic words and their fulfilments in Old Testament international events (Isaiah 44:6-8, 26, 2 Peter 1:19-21)

The fulfilment of New Testament prophecies (esp. the Destruction of Judea, outpouring of the Holy Spirit, etc. Matthew 23-24, Acts 1)

The supernatural "Life of Jesus Christ" (John 1:1, Colossians 1:15-20, Hebrews 1:1-3)

The unmatched philosophy of the Seminar on the Mount (Matthew 7:28)

The supernatural Death and Resurrection of Christ empirically witnessed and verified 1 Peter 1:3, 3:21-22, 2 Peter 1:16)

The miraculous Acts of the Apostles in the Early Church through the Holy Spirit outpouring from God the Father Acts 4:30-31, 5:12, 8:4-8)


This is not to say that natural theology (Romans 1:18-20), physical science, theistic philosophy, etc. don't have their place. A logical conclusion---without prejudiced barriers---of all of them will lead to the existence of a God.
But the Infallible Source of Truth is a good place to begin to explore and garner a list of the Proofs of God's Existence.
